# Radio Box Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, radio-button

when user clicks radio button yes then another multibox control should be un-visible repair that jquery if there is any problem

```
$('#MainContent_RadioButton1').change(function () {
            if ($("#MainContent_RadioButton1").is(':checked'))
                $("#MainContent_MultiSelectLiquor").show();  // checked
            else
                $("#MainContent_MultiSelectLiquor").hide(); // unchecked


        });
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text= " Yes" GroupName="a" />
                          &nbsp; &nbsp; <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text=" No" GroupName="a"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply do this:

```
$('#MainContent_RadioButton1').change(function () {
    $("#MainContent_MultiSelectLiquor").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Here in this code `.toggle(this.checked);` will be treated as `.toggle(true);` if checked and `.toggle(false);` if unchecked.

1. `.toggle(true);` is for show.
2. `.toggle(false);` is for hide.

Comment: I don't see in the [jQuery API docs that `.show(false)`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) is actually supported. It might be just undocumented but I have never heard of it before.

Comment: @Turnerj oops forgot to replace it with `.toggle()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use `ClientID` because ASP.net Changes Elements ID when It Renders on Browser as well as make changes as per below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun(obj) {

        if ($("#<%= RadioButton1.ClientID %> input:checked").val()=='Yes') {
            $("#MainContent_MultiSelectLiquor").css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            $("#MainContent_MultiSelectLiquor").css("display", "none");
        }
    }


</script> 


<asp:RadioButtonList   ID="RadioButton1"     runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" onchange="fun(this);"> </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No" onchange="fun(this);"> </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: or he could set the property ClientIDMode = Static on the radio button list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList CellPadding="10" ID="rblreporttype" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="0" Selected="True" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="1" />

                    </asp:RadioButtonList>



 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#rblreporttype').click(function () {

                try {


                    if ($('#rblreporttype :checked').prop('value') == 0) {
                      $("#MainContent_MultiSelectLiquor").show();//do your stuff
                    }
                    else {
                      $("#MainContent_MultiSelectLiquor").hide();   //do your stuff
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: It is worthwhile when adding an answer with code to explain the code a little. Dumping a whole bunch of code to the question asker isn't great. In your example, you have an unnecessary try/catch as well as you are only binding on the click event. If someone changes the selected radio button with their keyboard, what then?